# sourcetree - how to quickly resolve multiple merge conflicts and use master code?

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree, merge-conflict-resolution

I need to merge my master branch with my development branch but there are soooo many conflicts as I have been working on the master and not updating the development branch.

Is there a quick way to resolve these?  I simply want my development branch to be a copy of the master and am not too fussed about keeping the commits etc but am unable to delete the dev branch and start again.

I looked into doing a rebase but would have the same issues with conflicts.

*******UDATE*********

Disaster!! Now I am unable to switch back to the master branch because of all the conflicts. I have tried stashing the merge but that gave an error. So I then used the 'Discard' button and discarded the file changes hoping this would go back to how it was but now when I try to checkout master I get the error, "The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout:".

Can anyone help me out?  First and foremost I need to be able to switch to master.  Forget about the merge!

Comment: If you don't care about the changes on the development branch then just remove it and start over.

Comment: Unfortuantley I'm not allowed to remove the dev branch  :(  Do you have any other suggestions?  Many thanks

Comment: Disaster!! Now I am unable to switch back to the master branch because of all the conflicts.   I have tried stashing the merge but that gave an error.  So I then used the 'Discard' button and discarded the file changes hoping this would go back to how it was but now when I try to checkout master I get the error, "The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout:".   I'm in a pickle!!   :(

Comment: You are in the middle of an unfinished merge. You have to run [`git merge --abort`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#git-merge---abort) first. I don't have a copy of SourceTree at hand and I cannot remember if it provides such a command (it should be in the main menu). In case you cannot find it, open the terminal (it's a button on the right hand side of the toolbar) and type the command there. Then return to SourceTree and make it refresh the repository info.

Comment: Ive run that script but still cannot switch to master :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Disaster!! Now I am unable to switch back to the master branch because of all the conflicts. I have tried stashing the merge but that gave an error. So I then used the 'Discard' button and discarded the file changes hoping this would go back to how it was but now when I try to checkout master I get the error, "The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout:". I'm in a pickle!! :(

Run `git merge --abort` to put yourself back into the state you were before the conflicts appeared.

> I simply want my development branch to be a copy of the master and am not too fussed about keeping the commits etc.

If you're not fussed about keeping the commits, you could just copy the files in `master` to a temporary location, checkout `development` then paste the contents of the temporary directory into your repository workspace?

Comment: thanks for your quick response.  I have opened the terminal in sourectree and run the command.  So now I am no longer in the middle of a merge, however, when I try switching to master I get the same error, 'The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout:'

Comment: @LeeTee `git status` will tell you which files git is concerned about.

Comment: Ive added a screen grab of the error above.  Thsi error is exact same as previous to running git merge --abort

Comment: Run `git stash` to save your workspace changes, then change branches.

Comment: Strange, I just committed the files in develop and it allowed me to switch to Master, Phew!!  I will do what you suggested and copy and paste the files from master to develop. Thanks

Comment: Apologies, I didn't notice at first that those files weren't being tracked by git. `git stash` won't touch any untracked files.